# Why is the right half of the output for the Plot[(-x)^(2/3), {x, -30, 30}] missing?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, mathematica

I want to get a figure for $(-x)^{\frac23}$. After using the following code, I found that only the left part of the function $(-x)^{\frac23}$ was plotted.

```
Plot[(-x)^(2/3), {x, -30, 30}]
```

Here is a image of the output:
[image]

How can I get the right plot?

Comment: Because $(-x)^{2/3}$ is complex for $x >0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. The function domain of (-x)^(2/3) is x <= 0

Comment: @callculus: This expression is real for all real $x$. For example, $(-8)^{2/3}=4$. (There are also nonreal values of the expression for all real nonzero $x$ because of the root involved, but that's always true for any noninteger power.) The software probably isn't sophisticated enough to determine this. Note you could just plot $|x|^{2/3}$ because they are the same thing.

Comment: @SimonHan: No, the domain is all of $\mathbb R$. See my comment above.

Comment: @MPW Nonreal values for any non integer power ? $6^{2/3}=3.301927248...+0i$

Comment: Yes. There are finitely many possible values if and only if the power is rational. For example, $1^{1/3}$ has three values (the three cube roots of unity): $1$, $-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and $-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: @MPW I got it. I use `FunctionDomain` to find domain. So the result is not I really want again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the cube root of a number is potentially multivalued (depending on the context you are using it in) Mathematica uses the following conventions to differentiate between the different roots of $-1$:

- $-1$ represents the real number $-1$. I.e. the root with argument of $0$.
- $(-1)^\frac13$ represents the complex number $\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. I.e. the root with argument of $\frac{\pi}{3}$.
- $(-1)^\frac23$ represents the complex number $-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. I.e. the root with argument of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

So when you ask it to evaluate $(-x)$^$(2/3)$ you have inadvertently using the last notation and Mathematica thinks you want the complex answer with argument of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Hence why nothing is plotted.

If you wanted Mathematica to graph the real value answer you can get around it with either of the following commands:

> Plot[((-x)^2)^(1/3), {x, -30, 30}]

This will make it evaluate the squaring first before doing the cube root. Squaring first ensures the value being cube rooted is non-negative so Mathematica will only return a single value (the real root).

> Plot[Abs[(-x)^(2/3)],{x,-30,30}]

When applied to complex number the Abs function will find the modulus of the number (like how we use $|x|$ on the domains of reals vs complex).